# Kafka rolling upgrade with changing inter.broker.listener.name

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka 2.4.1 cluster with 3 brokers.
Listeners on these brokers were configured slightly not-bestpractice way. LISTENERS names defined like:

```
listener.security.protocol.map=LISTENER1:SSL, LISTENER2:SASL_PLAINTEXT
inter.broker.listener.name=LISTENER1
```

I want to upgrade this cluster to 2.7.1 and use listener names like CLIENT,INTERNAL. **But** when the new broker is started, topics are not moving into it.
Although I can see the new broker in zk /brokers/ids/X or on kafka-manager, but kafka-broker-api-versions.sh shows only old ones. If I set old listener names in new broker, it works well.

So my quiestion is - is there any workaround to connect old and new kafkas with different listener names (maybe add an alias) and during the rolling upgrade move to new listener names only. Or my only way is stop cluster and move to new listener names or use broker.listener.protocol instead (but it comes with stopping too).

Comment: Change listener name after rolling out. I mean do restart cycle again for that.

Comment: How? 
I mean, I have three brokers - B1,B2,B3
Let's assume I change listener names ater upgrade. 

1. change B1 -> restart B1
2. change B2 -> restart B2
3. change B3 -> restart B3

but on step 2  providers will mess up, cause B1 and B2 will say: "Im ok, bro" so will B3, he will refuse connections but will think he is alone on cluster and providers will suggest that there is a problem with cluster.

I mean, there will be a lottery if data is not corrupted and providers continue to write. Am I right?

Comment: I think the comment was simply saying don't do a version change and unnecessary properties (anything outside log format, for example) at the same time. You could attempt to modify Zookeeper data directly, but ultimately, I think the property change only works when either the controller or most of the nodes are the same. Having only one different broker with a different listener essentially temporarily removes it from the cluster

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for the idea to change directly on zk. Looks like I found a bug. 
When I changed /brokers/ids/1 kafka started to tell me why it's not gonna work.
```
[MetadataCache brokerId=1] Listeners are not identical across brokers
``
But before that it was just stuck on "Kafka server started". 
Anyway, changing zk didn't help, will upgrade with stopping.